# Kafka REST Proxy: connect only one consumer

Tags: kafka

I have Kafka topic "purchase2" with 2 partion and Kafka REST Proxy for consumers (from [this toturial](https://developer.confluent.io/get-started/rest/#introduction) ). When I run the first consumer for this topic, it all right:

```
 curl -X POST      -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json"      --data '{"name": "ci1", "format": "json", "auto.offset.reset": "earliest"}'      http://localhost:8082/consumers/cg1

 curl -X POST      -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json"      --data '{"topics":["purchases2"]}'      http://localhost:8082/consumers/cg1/instances/ci1/subscription

 curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json"  "http://localhost:8082/consumers/cg1/instances/ci1/records"
```

but if I try to run second consumer (new ID) and fetch rows:

```
 curl -X POST      -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json"      --data '{"name": "ci2", "format": "json", "auto.offset.reset": "earliest"}'      http://localhost:8082/consumers/cg1

 curl -X POST      -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json"      --data '{"topics":["purchases2"]}'      http://localhost:8082/consumers/cg1/instances/ci2/subscription

 curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json"  "http://localhost:8082/consumers/cg1/instances/ci2/records"
```

I get a lot of messages (in Kafka REST log) like: "Request joining group due to: group is already rebalancing " :

```
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:12,367] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-1, groupId=cg1] Request joining group due to: group is already rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:15,391] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-1, groupId=cg1] Request joining group due to: group is already rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:17,911] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-2, groupId=cg1] JoinGroup failed: The coordinator is not aware of this member. Need to re-join the group. Sent generation was Generation{generationId=-1, memberId='consumer-cg1-2-c3f649ce-934c-4e8a-a87a-d2e85ac82b54', protocol='null'} (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:17,911] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-2, groupId=cg1] Resetting generation and member id due to: encountered UNKNOWN_MEMBER_ID from JOIN_GROUP response (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:17,912] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-2, groupId=cg1] Request joining group due to: encountered UNKNOWN_MEMBER_ID from JOIN_GROUP response (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:17,913] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-2, groupId=cg1] Request joining group due to: rebalance failed due to 'The coordinator is not aware of this member.' (UnknownMemberIdException) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:17,915] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-2, groupId=cg1] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:17,919] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-2, groupId=cg1] Request joining group due to: need to re-join with the given member-id: consumer-cg1-2-ff236f69-f902-4294-847a-8bf4940354ef (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:17,919] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-2, groupId=cg1] Request joining group due to: rebalance failed due to 'The group member needs to have a valid member id before actually entering a consumer group.' (MemberIdRequiredException) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:17,919] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-2, groupId=cg1] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:18,414] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-1, groupId=cg1] Request joining group due to: group is already rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:21,439] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-1, groupId=cg1] Request joining group due to: group is already rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:24,461] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-1, groupId=cg1] Request joining group due to: group is already rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:27,488] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-1, groupId=cg1] Request joining group due to: group is already rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:30,511] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-1, groupId=cg1] Request joining group due to: group is already rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:33,535] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-1, groupId=cg1] Request joining group due to: group is already rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:36,560] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-1, groupId=cg1] Request joining group due to: group is already rebalancing (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:38,475] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-1, groupId=cg1] consumer poll timeout has expired. This means the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time processing messages. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:38,475] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-1, groupId=cg1] Member consumer-cg1-1-9dc34071-0a6d-4fce-8e11-9e18c6bbc372 sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator broker:29092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) due to consumer poll timeout has expired. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:38,477] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-1, groupId=cg1] Resetting generation and member id due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:38,477] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-1, groupId=cg1] Request joining group due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:38,482] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-2, groupId=cg1] Successfully joined group with generation Generation{generationId=38, memberId='consumer-cg1-2-ff236f69-f902-4294-847a-8bf4940354ef', protocol='range'} (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:38,484] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-2, groupId=cg1] Finished assignment for group at generation 38: {consumer-cg1-2-ff236f69-f902-4294-847a-8bf4940354ef=Assignment(partitions=[purchases2-0, purchases2-1])} (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:38,495] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-2, groupId=cg1] Successfully synced group in generation Generation{generationId=38, memberId='consumer-cg1-2-ff236f69-f902-4294-847a-8bf4940354ef', protocol='range'} (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:38,498] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-2, groupId=cg1] Notifying assignor about the new Assignment(partitions=[purchases2-0, purchases2-1]) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:38,498] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-2, groupId=cg1] Adding newly assigned partitions: purchases2-0, purchases2-1 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:38,506] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-2, groupId=cg1] Setting offset for partition purchases2-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=11, offsetEpoch=Optional[0], currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[broker:29092 (id: 1 rack: null)], epoch=0}} (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
rest-proxy    | [2023-09-21 09:58:38,506] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-cg1-2, groupId=cg1] Setting offset for partition purchases2-1 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=22, offsetEpoch=Optional[0], currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[broker:29092 (id: 1 rack: null)], epoch=0}} (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
```

Rebalance and messages  lasts about max.poll.interval.ms , while first consumer will be  deleted. During that time nobody can get data from topic. And the second consumer connects only when first   consumer will be kick out by timeout (max.poll.interval.ms). It repeats every time I try to start any second consumer. Topic has 2 partions and it's normal have two consumers, one for each partion. But for some reason I can't activate second consumer.

Answer (score 0):

This problem in Kafka REST version: 7.3.0, in version 7.5.0  the problem was solved.

For Kafka REST 6.2.7  the same situation but another messages in log :

```
Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
```